# Can I override views in Web Forms like I can in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, episerver

In ASP.NET MVC I can typically override view e.g. by putting a view with the same name in the `DisplayTemplates` folder. If I wanted to override the way images are rendered, I could put something like `Images.cshtml` in the folder.

Now, I want to override the way xforms are rendered in EPiServer. I know how to do this in ASP.NET MVC, but this project uses Webforms.

I have tried to search, but the documentation seems sparse on the subject. In ASP.NET MVC, I could e.g. extend the search engine to search specific locations to look for my views, or put them where ASP.NET looks by default.

This doesn't seem to work in Web Forms. Does anyone know how?

EDIT: EPiServer has an `.ascx` file which it uses to render an XForm with. I want to tell ASP.NET to use my `.ascx` file instead. To do this I need to tell ASP.NET to look for my `.ascx` file, e.g. by telling the ASP.NET view engine to look for my `.ascx` in a specific folder, or by placing it somewhere the view engine looks by default.

How do I do this?

Comment: Be more specific. What output do you have and what output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I added some information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace it everywhere just replace the ascx file. Otherwise I am afraid the answer is no. Web Forms does not look for alternative locations for files by default as controls are usually specified using the full path or the class name. What you want to do would be equivalent of C# looking for alternative namespaces when it cannot find a class name. There are ways to achieve this behavior in Web Forms like for example Dynamic Data but ascx controls is not this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Property web control to display the value you can create your own custom PropertyControl and register it for your type in the PropertyControlFactory. This way you can control how your property will be rendered.

While this doesn't allow you to point out your .ascx directly, you can load it in your server control if you prefer that.

For code examples and a great summary of this (and some other) ways of customizing property rendering in EPiServer, see Mathias Kunto's blog post at http://blog.mathiaskunto.com/2012/03/05/being-friends-with-the-propertycontrolclassfactory-or-101-ways-to-change-episerver-built-in-property-appearances/.